# Use Unicode Character in Menu Instead of Graphic

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to use this unicode character ▼ in place of a tiny gif graphic in this menu...

[image: Menu using image]

I know I need to use something like:

```
#nav a:hover:after {
    content: "▼";
    color: #fff;
    }
```

But that simply displays the unicode character inline after each menu item like this...

[image: Menu with Unicode character]

I can't figure out how to make the unicode character centered over each menu item like I was able to do with the graphic. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
#nav a {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#nav a:hover:before {
  content: "▼";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

See the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/njqd7gnp/2/

Answer (score 1):

Give `position:absolute` to your unicode character and adjust top and left position.

Try this:

```
#nav a{
    position:relative;
}
#nav a:hover::after {
    color: #fff;
    content: "▼";
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I liked Jerad's solution a bit better because it automatically centers the unicode character, but your solution also works.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding the shape after the text itself `<li>about &#9660</li>`
Then in the CSS, you make the `visibility:hidden;` and appear it when `:hover` by using `visibility:visible;`

Read more about visibility if you are unsure http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: This is not related to the original question